# AngularJS Check/Uncheck All checkboxes from ng-repeat object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/a09koefn/)

I've a table in which each row has checkbox and another checkbox in  to check-all rows (checkboxes) and send ID of selected/all row(s) as JSON object.

I've an object array from (GET) response (server-side pagination is enabled) and stored it in **itemsList** $scope variable.

Following is my code.

**View**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="allItemsSelected ng-change="selectAll()"></th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in itemsList track by $index" ng-class="{selected: item.isChecked}">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-change="selectItem(item)">
            </td>
            <td>{{item.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.itemsList = [
    {
        id : 1,
        date : '2019-04-04T07:50:56'
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        date : '2019-04-04T07:50:56'
    },
    {
        id : 3,
        date : '2019-04-04T07:50:56'
    }
];
$scope.allItemsSelected = false;
$scope.selectedItems = [];

// This executes when entity in table is checked
$scope.selectItem = function (item) {

    // If any entity is not checked, then uncheck the "allItemsSelected" checkbox
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsList.length; i++) {
        if (!this.isChecked) {
            $scope.allItemsSelected = false;
            // $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.itemsList[i].id);
            $scope.selectedItems.push(item.id);
            return
        }
    }

    //If not the check the "allItemsSelected" checkbox
    $scope.allItemsSelected = true;

};

// This executes when checkbox in table header is checked
$scope.selectAll = function() {

    // Loop through all the entities and set their isChecked property
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsList.length; i++) {
        $scope.itemsList[i].isChecked = $scope.allItemsSelected;

        $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.itemsList[i].id);
    }

};
```

**Below are the issues I'm facing...**

- If you check fiddle example than you can see that on **checkAll()** the array is updated with all available list. But if click again on **checkAll()** instead of remove list from array it again add another row on same object array.
- Also i want to do same (add/remove from array) if click on any row's checkbox
- If i manually check all checkboxes than the thead checkbox should also be checked.

Comment: Hello guys, any help on this one?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFIDDLE for the issue?

Comment: @rahim.nagori already did, please check all the way top in question...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are on the right path. I don't think is a good idea to have an array only for the selected items, instead you could use the `isSelected` property of the items. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MSclavi/95zvm8yc/2/.

If you have to send the selected items to the backend, you can filter the items if they are checked with

```
var selectedItems = $scope.itemsList.filter(function (item) {
    return !item.isChecked;
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This will help you for one of the two doubts:

```
$scope.selectAll = function() {
    if($scope.allItemsSelected){
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsList.length; i++) {
            $scope.itemsList[i].isChecked = $scope.allItemsSelected;
            $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.itemsList[i].id);
        }
    }else{
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsList.length; i++) {
            scope.itemsList[i].isChecked = $scope.allItemsSelected;
        }
        $scope.selectedItems = [];
    }
};
```

I'm looking for something to achieve solution to point 2.
**ng-checked** can be used but it is not good to use **ng-checked** with **ng-model**.